# Positioning a list with jquery hover effect

Tags: jquery, css, list, hover, positioning

Need help getting the list within the wrapper div. Also the images that I have as "items" are slightly different widths, either way I feel there is a solution, however, I just can't seem to find it. If anyone knows of a simpler code for fade hover effect maybe that's easiest. The jquery is pretty good here just having problems positioning. Thanks!

Here's what it looks like thus far -
http://marisareviewsfilms.com/demo

Here's how I want it to look - http://marisareviewsfilms.com/lisa#

My CSS (the borders are just to guide me for now):

```
#wrapper {
width: 827px;
height: 577px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.gallery li {
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
height: 577px;
display: ;
width: 129px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid green;
}

img.grey {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
}

img.color {
position: absolute;
left: 0; 
top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine. However, the browser defaults are messing with the positioning.

Just change the following

1. At the beginning of the css apply a [**reset css**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).
2. Add a [**clearfix**](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) class to the `ul.gallery`

**Update**

The image slices you are using are `131px`, except the first, and last one (which are `148px`, `151px` respectively). 
So change this in the CSS :

```
.gallery li {
    width: 131px;
}
.gallery li:first-child {
    width: 148px;
}
.gallery li:last-child {
    width: 151px;
}
```

However, this will work on all modern browsers.
In case you want to support `IE7,8`,
add classes to the first and last `li`, and then put the css accordingly (as above).

```
<li class="first">
...
<li class="last">
```

**NOTE** : Do remove the green/blue borders, since they would take 1px width each.

Comment: This is really great. Thank you! Here's how it looks so far - http://marisareviewsfilms.com/demo. I'm trying to figure out how to code different widths within the same list, so that it looks like this - http://marisareviewsfilms.com/lisa#. I'm not sure if that's possible...

Comment: It worked! http://marisareviewsfilms.com/demo. I was wondering how to specify that, now I know for future coding as well, thank you so much. I voted up, let me know if there's anything else I can do to rate you well (still learning the ropes on here).    Also, I could have used CSS to code the color checker but thought it would be easier this way since each color column is to be a link. Just in case you were wondering :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to get you going:

First, if you add margin: 0 and padding: 0 to .gallery, it'll place it within the wrapper.

Secondly, I'd change the way you're exporting the images. The curved dark background should be part of the ul, and you can create that in css/with an image.

Then, export each column of coloured blocks (with a transparent background), and position them similar to the way you've done now.

You'll have a lot less problems doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In somes browsers `<ul>` (`.gallery` here) have a 40px `padding-left`,
you can correct it with a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Or by writing

```
ul.gallery{
  padding-left:0;
}
```